# What specialty of the Prophet Muhammad (SAW) is meant in 33:50?

Tags: tafseer, prophet-muhammad

What exactly is meant by the bold part in the below verse:

> O Prophet, indeed We have made lawful to you your wives to whom you
> have given their due compensation and those your right hand possesses
> from what Allah has returned to you [of captives] and the daughters of
> your paternal uncles and the daughters of your paternal aunts and the
> daughters of your maternal uncles and the daughters of your maternal
> aunts who emigrated with you and a believing woman if she gives
> herself to the Prophet [and] if the Prophet wishes to marry her,
> **[this is] only for you, excluding the [other] believers.** We certainly know what We have made obligatory upon them concerning their
> wives and those their right hands possess, [but this is for you] in
> order that there will be upon you no discomfort. And ever is Allah
> Forgiving and Merciful.

I guess the specialty exists in this part since it is the last thing that is said:

> a believing woman if she gives herself to the Prophet [and] if the
> Prophet wishes to marry her

Is that correct? And if so please explain how this is different for other believers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have read tafsir of this ayat recently (Tafhim ul Quran in Urdu) . There are two meanings. First let us come to the specific meaning.

If a woman offered herself as wife to Prophet Muhammad (Peace on Him) he could marry her without paying mehr. Other men have to pay suitable mehr (depending on  financial conditions of people involved) for marriage.

Hazrat Maimoona (Peace on Her) offered herself to Prophet Muhammad (Peace on Him) for marriage after this verse. Prophet Muhammad (Peace on Him) married her. Still he paid her mehr without any demand. She was the last mother of Muslims.

There is a general meaning attached to this verse. There are some rules in Islam which are meant for Prophet Muhammad (Peace on Him) only. For example he was allowed more than four wives. Tahajjud was a Fard for him.